# Determining number of surnames using sumifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to find the number of customers with the surname X. The list of names are in Column A

```
=SUMIF("surname range", A2 ,"dummy count column aka values of 1")
```

However, I want to only sum up exact matches. Therefore, if i'm searching for the surname "hon", I don't want to count "maHONey" or "mcmaHON" or "atHONy" towards the total.

I could use the formula

```
=SUMIF("surname range", "hon" ,"dummy count column aka values of 1")
```

except I have a list of 400 surnames and manual entry isn't practical. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not COUNTIF() so you do not need a dummy column?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use COUNTIF()
2. Wrap the COUNTIF in SUM() with the range in which you have the desired surnames to count:

Example

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A,B1:B400))
```

When exiting edit mode use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.